# Не выводятся записи из цикла WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Хочу вывести записи с помощью такого цикла, но вместо записей выводится ссылка на эту же страницу. Как решить эту задачу, а то все перерыл и не понял. Спасибо!

```
    <?php if (have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <!-- post -->
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="card">
                <div class="card__img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>');"></div>
                <div class="card__description">
                    <h2 class="card__title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                    <span class="card__date"><?php  the_date('j F Y','',' г') ?></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- post navigation -->
        <?php else: ?>
            <!-- no posts found -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по картинке, вы пытаетесь использовать этот цикл на странице, в шаблоне страницы. Всё верно - будет выведена 1 запись о самой странице, потому что уже сформирован главный цикл WordPress, в него попала текущая страница, она и выводится.

Вам надо сформировать свой цикл по нужным записям. Делается это так:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Цикл
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <!-- post -->
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="card">
            <div class="card__img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>');"></div>
            <div class="card__description">
                <h2 class="card__title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                <span class="card__date"><?php  the_date('j F Y','',' г') ?></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    <?php
    }
    // post navigation
} else {
    // Постов не найдено
}
/* Возвращаем оригинальные данные поста. Сбрасываем $post. */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Подробнее на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query).